# Is handle_info guaranteed to be executed immediately after init with timeout 0?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I am getting a strange error report that makes me think some calls are being executed before the gen_server initialization.

Here is the init code:

```
init([ResourceId]) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    {ok, {not_initialized, ResourceId}, 0}.
```

Here is the handle_info that should initialize the resource.

```
handle_info(timeout, {not_initialized, ResourceId}) ->
    Resource = data_store:get_resource(ResourceId),
    {noreply, Resource, ?CACHE_TIMEOUT};
```

the return value of data_store:get_resource(ResourceId) is the #resouce{} record, used to match all the handle_call methods.

The crash report with a function clause since the process is still not initialized.

```
=CRASH REPORT==== 1-Feb-2013::14:20:03 ===
crasher:
  initial call: gbanga_resources:init/1
  pid: <0.11772.0>  
  registered_name: []
  exception exit: {function_clause,
                      [{gbanga_resources,terminate,
                           [{function_clause,
                                [{gbanga_resources,handle_call,
                                     [get_resource,
                                      {<0.11658.0>,#Ref<0.0.0.240914>},
                                      {not_initialized,12697711}],
                                     [{file,"src/gbanga_resources.erl"},
                                      {line,120}]},
                                 {gen_server,handle_msg,5,
                                     [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,588}]},
                                 {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                     [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]},
                            {not_initialized,12697711}],
                           [{file,"src/gbanga_resources.erl"},{line,176}]},
                       {gen_server,terminate,6,
                           [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,722}]},
                       {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                           [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}
    in function  gen_server:terminate/6 (gen_server.erl, line 725)
  ancestors: [gbanga_resources_sup,gbanga_workers_sup,<0.92.0>]
  messages: [{'$gen_call',{<0.11638.0>,#Ref<0.0.0.240915>},get_resource},
                {'$gen_call',{<0.11633.0>,#Ref<0.0.0.240916>},get_resource}]
  links: [<0.6609.0>]
  dictionary: []
```

This should never happens if the handle_info timeout allways is called before any handle_call.

Does anyone knows why this is happening ?

Comment: In my opinion, the right way to do this is to call "Resource = data_store:get_resource(ResourceId)" within the init function and avoid this uninitialized step

Comment: That's how it was and I think I will leave it that way. I was trying to gain some performance since on some tests when there are several resources loaded at once the supervisor becomes a bottleneck, but maybe I will model the problem differently if this becomes a real problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guaranteed? No. The timeout is a message like any other. If during the middle of the init function you receive a message from another process, you will likely process that message first.

That being said, the init function ***for OTP processes*** like gen_server is synchronous from the calling process, meaning that the process will have finished its init function by the time you receive the Pid, making it exceedingly difficult for another process to send a message to it before it has a chance to execute the timeout.

Of course, I would not recommend using a timeout for this behavior. It's less well-defined what will happen, because the process is more-or-less yielding when it returns from init, and timers in Erlang are not guaranteed to fire exactly on time (timer:sleep(5000) will sleep *at least* five seconds, not exactly five seconds). Instead, send a message to `self()`; this lets the process know immediately that it has work to do, as the message winds up in your mailbox *before* init returns.

Comment: The init function for OTP processes is synchronous because the calling process waits for an acknowledge message from the new process. See: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proc_lib.html#init_ack-1

Comment: But it wouldn't be the same with a message to self? I mean it will still be possible from other processes to squeeze in a message right? specially since the resources are registered using the id so they don't need to know the pid.

Comment: Well, considering that the init function is synchronous, sending a message to self from init guarantees that it's the first message in the inbox, as opposed to a timeout of 0 (which requires evaluating the timer and sending a message *after* the completion of init).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I have it a lot more clear now.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are doing this to keep the initialisation of the server short. Otherwise there is no real reason not to call your `data_store:get_resource/1` function directly in `init/1`.

A "standard" way of doing this is to in `init/1` just do a **cast** to yourself.

```
init([ResourceId]) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    gen_server:cast(self(), init_phase_2),                 %Must be a cast!
    {ok, {not_initialized, ResourceId}}.

handle_cast(init_phase_2, {not_initialized,ResourceId}) ->
    Resource = data_store:get_resource(ResourceId),
    {noreply, Resource}.
```

You **KNOW** this will be the first message processed as the Pid has not been returned so no-one else can have sent a message to the server.

Comment: If there is no real reason otherwise this must be the reason right ? ;). Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AgustinCautin It's a good reason too! Your supervisor starts its children in sequence so if they have long start up times then it is not good. This would allow them to do their initialisation in parallel.

Comment: I think the language specification does not guarantee that your message will arrive first. I only found guarantees for ordering of messages of the same sender (10.5.4). So a message from another sender might arrive first. Probably no implementation would do this, but do you have some source for your claim?

Comment: @peq since he is one of the original authors of the language I would take is word for it. But also check the  Soup d'Campbells comment, inside the init nobody knows the pid yet, and the mailbox is a queue meaning that if A sends a message to B and then C sends a message to B, the message from A is put first in the mailbox, basically you can treat the mailbox of B as a queue of messages, so the order will be preserved.