# If the init/1 function in a gen_server process sends a message to itself, is it guaranteed to arrive before any other message?

Tags: concurrency, erlang

There is a pattern I've seen occasionally where the `init/1` function of a `gen_server` process will send a message to itself signalling that it should be initialized. The purpose of this is for the `gen_server` process to initialize itself asynchronously so that the process spawning it doesn't have to wait. Here is an example:

```
-module(test).
-compile(export_all).

init([]) ->
    gen_server:cast(self(), init),
    {ok, {}}.

handle_cast(init, {}) ->
    io:format("initializing~n"),
    {noreply, lists:sum(lists:seq(1,10000000))};
handle_cast(m, X) when is_integer(X) ->
    io:format("got m. X: ~p~n", [X]),
    {noreply, X}.

b() ->
    receive P -> {} end,
    gen_server:cast(P, m),
    b().

test() ->
    B = spawn(fun test:b/0),
    {ok, A} = gen_server:start_link(test,[],[]),
    B ! A.
```

The process assumes that the `init` message will be received before any other message - otherwise it will crash. Is it possible for this process to get the `m` message before the `init` message?

---

Let's assume there's no process sending messages to random pids generated by `list_to_pid`, since any application doing this will probably not work at all, regardless of the answer to this question.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648304/is-handle-info-guaranteed-to-executed-first-in-a-process-after-init-with-timeout).

Comment: I can't tell if any of these answers are correct because they all seem to make the assumption that this question is true: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18018780/2213023

Answer (score 5):

Theoretical answer to the question is it possible for **a** process to get a message before the init message? is **YES**.
But practically (when no process is doing list_to_pid and sending a message) to this process the answer is **NO** provided the gen_server is not a registered process.

This is because the return of gen_server:start_link ensures that callback init of gen_server is executed. Thus initialize message is the first message in the process message queue before any other process gets the Pid to send a message. **Thus your process is safe and does not receive any other message before init.**

But same does not go true for registered process as there can be a process which might be sending message to the gen_server using registered name even before it completes callback init function.
Lets consider this test function.

```
test() ->
    Times = lists:seq(1,1000),
    spawn(gen_server, start_link,[{local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []]),
    [gen_server:cast(?MODULE, No) || No <-Times].
```

The sample output is

```
1> async_init:test().
Received:356
Received:357
[ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,
 ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok|...]
Received:358
Received:359
2> Received:360
2> Received:361
...
2> Received:384
2> Received:385
2> Initializing
2> Received:386
2> Received:387
2> Received:388
2> Received:389 
...
```

You can see that gen_server received messages from 356 to 385 messages before initialize. 
Thus the async callback does not work in registered name scenario.

This can be solved by two ways

1.Register the process after Pid is returned.

> ```
>  start_link_reg() ->
>       {ok, Pid} = gen_server:start(?MODULE, [], []),
>       register(?MODULE, Pid).
> ```

2.Or in handle_cast for init message register the process.

> ```
> handle_cast(init, State) ->
>     register(?MODULE, self()),
>     io:format("Initializing~n"),
>     {noreply, State};
> ```

The sample output after this change is

```
1> async_init:test().
Initializing
Received:918
Received:919
[ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,
 ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok|...]
Received:920
2> Received:921
2> Received:922
...
```

Thus sending a message to itself for initializing does not ensure that it is the first message that it receives but with bit of changes in the code (and design) can ensure that it is the first to be executed.

Comment: The premise, "the return of gen_server:start_link ensures that callback init of gen_server is executed." does not imply the conclusion, "Thus initialize message is the first message in the process message queue before any other process gets the Pid to send a message." See http://stackoverflow.com/q/18018780/2213023. But maybe there is some other way that gen_server makes the guarantee.

Comment: Even according to the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18018780/2213023). The handle_cast will make sure that the message is sent to the mailbox before the next call (return) of init is executed. Thus with the combination of sending message before start_link return ensures that this is the first message in the message queue before the caller gets the Pid to send next message.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean "the message is *put in* to the mailbox before", not "the message is sent to the mailbox before". There's a huge difference.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you would be safe in the assumption that the 'init' message will be received before 'm'.  In general (and especially if you register your process) this is not true though.

If you want to be 100% safe knowing that your init code will run first you can do something like:

```
start_link(Args...) ->
    gen_server:start_link(test, [self(), Args...], []).

init([Parent, Args...]) ->
    do_your_synchronous_start_stuff_here,
    proc_lib:init_ack(Parent, {ok, self()}),
    do_your_async_initializing_here,
    io:format("initializing~n"),
    {ok, State}.
```

I didn't test this, so I don't know if the "bonus" init_ack will print an ugly message to the terminal or not. If it does, the code has to be expanded slightly, but the general idea still stands.  Let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Indeed, this approach means sending an extra message to the supervisor which is an **undefined behavior**. Technically, `supervisor` will simply output the message to stdout, but it could crash or interpret this message. Alternatively, you could rewrite the logic from gen_server and call `proc_lib:start_link/3,4,5`, register the name (if required), then call `proc_lib:init_ack/1,2`, perform asynchronous initialization and eventually call `gen_server:enter_loop/3,4,5`. In practice, this is not required and sending a message to self in `init/1` can be safe.

Comment: With focus on **can**.  There are a lot of situations where it's not safe.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code is safe and `m` is always received after `init`.

However, from a **theoretical** point of view, if `init/1` handler of a gen_server sends a message to itself, using `gen_server:cast/2` or the send primitive, **it is not guaranteed** to be the first message.

There is no way to guarantee this simply because `init/1` is executed within the process of the gen_server, therefore after the process was created and allocated a pid and a mailbox. In non-SMP mode, the scheduler **can** schedule out the process under some load before the init function is called or before the message is sent, since calling a function (such as `gen_server:cast/2` or the init handler for that matter) generates a reduction and the BEAM emulator tests whether it's time to give some time to other processes. In SMP mode, you can have another scheduler that will run some code sending a message to your process.

What distinguishes theory from practice is the way to find out about the existence of the process (in order to send it a message before the `init` message). Code could use links from the supervisor, the registered name, the list of processes returned by `erlang:processes()` or even call `list_to_pid/1` with random values or unserialize pids with `binary_to_term/1`. Your node might even get a message from another node with a serialized pid, especially considering that creation number wraps around after 3 (see your other question [Wrong process getting killed on other node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194761/wrong-process-getting-killed-on-other-node/18208425)).

This is unlikely in practice. As a result, from a practical point of view, every time this pattern is used, the **code can be designed to ensure `init` message is received first** and the server is initialized before it receives other messages.

**If the gen_server is a registered process**, you would start it from a supervisor and ensure that all clients are started afterward in the supervision tree or introduce some kind of (probably inferior) synchronization mechanism. This is required even if you do not use this pattern of asynchronous initialization (otherwise clients could not reach the server). Of course, you might still have issues in case of crashes and restarts of this gen_server, but this is true whatever the scenario, and you can only be saved by a carefully crafted supervision tree.

**If the gen_server is not registered** or referred to by name, clients will eventually pass the pid to `gen_server:call/2,3` or `gen_server:cast/2` which they would obtain through the supervisor which calls `gen_server:start_link/3`. `gen_server:start_link/3` only returns when `init/1` returned and therefore after the `init` message was enqueued. This is exactly what your code above does.

Comment: "code can be designed to not allow messages to arrive before initialization." I'm not sure I'm understanding this. Do you really mean, "code can be designed with the assumption that the `init` message will be received first"?

Comment: Actually, I meant that code can be designed to **make sure** the init message will be received first. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

gen_server uses proc_lib:init_ack to make sure that the process is properly started before returning the pid from start_link. So the message sent in init will be the first message.

Comment: How about registered processes? Can I send a message to a process name before `init` finishes?

Comment: Answering my own question, if you send a message `A` to the registered process before the `init` function sends itself a `B` message, the `A` message will be processed before `B`.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  There are multiple ways to send a message to a process before it has properly started.  The easiest being erlang:processes() or for that matter looking at the links of the supervisor.  It's even common in the case of a registered process since that happens before init runs.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not 100%** safe!
In `gen.erl` line 117-129, we can see this:

```
init_it(GenMod, Starter, Parent, Mod, Args, Options) ->
init_it2(GenMod, Starter, Parent, self(), Mod, Args, Options).

init_it(GenMod, Starter, Parent, Name, Mod, Args, Options) ->
    case name_register(Name) of
        true ->
            init_it2(GenMod, Starter, Parent, Name, Mod, Args, Options);
        {false, Pid} ->
            proc_lib:init_ack(Starter, {error, {already_started, Pid}})
    end.

init_it2(GenMod, Starter, Parent, Name, Mod, Args, Options) ->
    GenMod:init_it(Starter, Parent, Name, Mod, Args, Options).
```

In `init_it/7` the process register its **Name** first, and then in `init_it2/7` it calls `GenMod:init_it/6` in which it calls your `init/1` function.

Although, before gen_server:start_link returns, it is hardly to guess the new process id. However, if you send a message to the server **with the registered Name**, and the message arrives before your gen_server:cast is called, your code will be wrong.

Daniel's solution may be right, but I'm not quite sure whether two `proc_lib:init_ack` will cause an error or not. However, the parent would never like to receive an unexpected message. >_<

Here is **another solution**. Keep **a flag** in your **gen_servser state** to mark whether the server is initialized. And when you receive `m`, just check whether the server is initialized, if not, gen_cast `m` to yourself.

This is a little troublesome solution, but I'm sure it is right. =_=

I'm a freshman here, how I wish I could add a comment. >"<

Comment: It's trivial to work around the duplicate init_ack, 5-10 lines of code or so.  That's not an excuse to have a flag that needs to be checked *every single time* the gen_server receives a message.

Comment: Yeah, adding a flag is not a good solution, I agree... However it is actually another solution...=_= Aha!

Comment: Thanks for your comment~ It's really an encouragement for a fresher like me!