# If you send a message to a process before giving out its pid, is it guaranteed to recieve that message first?

Tags: concurrency, erlang

Say there is a process `B`, which receives a pid and sends `m2` to it. If you spawn `A` and send it `m1`, and then send `A` to `B` , is `A` guaranteed to get `m1` before `m2`?

In other words, can this crash?

```
-module(test).
-compile(export_all).

test() ->
    B = spawn_link(fun() -> receive P -> P ! m2 end end),
    A = spawn_link(fun() -> receive X -> X=m1 end end),
    A ! m1,
    B ! A.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code cannot crash because **all processes are local**.

```
B = spawn_link(fun() -> receive P -> P ! m2 end end),     % 1
A = spawn_link(fun() -> receive X -> X=m1 end end),       % 2
A ! m1,                                                   % 3
B ! A.                                                    % 4
```

When evaluating line 3, both BEAM emulator and HiPE invoke the [erl_send](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/397caf87b39380f5517954320f25fdf9b97d0c90/erts/emulator/beam/bif.c#L2129) built-in function (BIF). Since A is a local process, erl_send (actually [do_send](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/397caf87b39380f5517954320f25fdf9b97d0c90/erts/emulator/beam/bif.c#L2025)) eventually calls [erts_send_message](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/397caf87b39380f5517954320f25fdf9b97d0c90/erts/emulator/beam/erl_message.c#L873) which [enqueues](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/397caf87b39380f5517954320f25fdf9b97d0c90/erts/emulator/beam/erl_message.c#L1051) the message in the mailbox. In SMP mode, the thread actually acquires a lock on the mailbox.

So when evaluating line 4 and sending A to process B, A already has m1 in its mailbox. So `m2` can only be enqueued after `m1`.

Whether this result is particular of the current implementation of Erlang is debatable, even if this is not guaranteed by documentation. Indeed, each process need a mailbox and this mailbox needs to be filled somehow. This is done synchronously on line 3. To do it asynchronously would either require another thread in-between or several mailboxes per process (e.g. one per scheduler to avoid the lock on the mailbox). Yet I do not think this would make sense performance-wise.

If processes **A and B were remote but within the same node**, the behavior is slightly different but the result would be the same with the current implementation of Erlang. On line 3, message `m1` will be enqueued for the remote node and on line 4, message `A` will be enqueued afterwards. When remote node will dequeue messages, it will first write `m1` to A's mailbox before writing `A` to B's mailbox.

If process **A was remote and B was local**, the result would still be the same. On line 3, message `m1` will be enqueued for the remote node and on line 4, message will be written to B, but then on line 1, message `m2` will be enqueued to remote node after `m1`. So A will get messages in m1, m2 order.

Likewise, if process **A was local and B was remote**, A will get the message copied to its mailbox on line 3 before anything is sent over the network to B's node.

With the current version of Erlang, the only way for this to crash is to have **A and B on distinct remote nodes**. In this case, `m1` is enqueued to A's node before `A` is enqueued to B's node. However, delivery of these messages is not synchronous. Delivery to B's node could happen first, for example if many messages are already enqueued for A's node.

The following code (sometimes) triggers the crash by filling queue to A's node with junk messages that slow delivery of `m1`.

`$ erl -sname node_c@localhost`

```
C = spawn_link(fun() ->
    A = receive {process_a, APid} -> APid end,
    B = receive {process_b, BPid} -> BPid end,
    ANode = node(A),
    lists:foreach(fun(_) ->
        rpc:cast(ANode, erlang, whereis, [user])
    end, lists:seq(1, 10000)),
    A ! m1,
    B ! A
end),
register(process_c, C).
```

`$ erl -sname node_b@localhost`

```
B = spawn_link(fun() -> receive P -> P ! m2 end end),
C = rpc:call(node_c@localhost, erlang, whereis, [process_c]),
C ! {process_b, B}.
```

`$ erl -sname node_a@localhost`

```
A = spawn_link(fun() -> receive X -> X = m1 end, io:format("end of A\n") end),
C = rpc:call(node_c@localhost, erlang, whereis, [process_c]),
C ! {process_a, A}.
```

Answer (score 1):

If both the two processes are **on the same node**, it is true that A is guaranteed to get m1 before m2.

But when the two processes are **on different nodes**, it is not guaranteed.

There is a paper `Programming Distributed Erlang Applications: Pitfalls and Recipes` about this problem.

Here is the link: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.116.9929&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Your problem is in **2.2** of this paper, and I think it is really an intereting paper!

Comment: Why do you think it's guaranteed for processes on the same node? In that paper the answer seems to be "maybe".

Comment: @Dog In another paper called `A Semantics For Distributed Erlang`, it is said that _Messages are delivered instantly_. And `m1` is guaranteed to arrive before `m2` on the same node. Here is the link: http://www.erlang.org/workshop/2005/ErlangSemantics.pdf

Comment: However we should not rely on this, I think.